# Magento add product info to More Info tab

Tags: php, magento, tabs, product

I am trying to show Magento product stock information and Magento product price information in the tab `Description`.

I have copied the following code from:
`app/design/frontend/default/theme/template/catalog/product/view.phtml`

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_data') ?>
```

into:
`app/design/frontend/default/theme/template/catalog/product/view/description.phtml`

This displays the stock and price information on view.phtml, but nothing is shown in `description.phtml`.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `product_type_data` block is a child of `product.info` (from where you actually copied it) and not `description` block.

So what do you have to do is to add the following code to `local.xml` file of your theme:

```
<PRODUCT_TYPE_simple>
    <reference name="product.description">
        <block type="catalog/product_view_type_simple" name="product.info.simple" as="product_type_data" template="catalog/product/view/type/default.phtml">
            <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.simple.extra" as="product_type_data_extra" translate="label">
                <label>Product Extra Info</label>
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
</PRODUCT_TYPE_simple>
<PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable>
    <reference name="product.description">
        <block type="catalog/product_view_type_configurable" name="product.info.configurable" as="product_type_data" template="catalog/product/view/type/default.phtml">
            <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.configurable.extra" as="product_type_data_extra" translate="label">
                <label>Product Extra Info</label>
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
</PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable>
<PRODUCT_TYPE_grouped>
    <reference name="product.description">
        <block type="catalog/product_view_type_grouped" name="product.info.grouped" as="product_type_data" template="catalog/product/view/type/grouped.phtml">
            <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.grouped.extra" as="product_type_data_extra" translate="label">
                <label>Product Extra Info</label>
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
</PRODUCT_TYPE_grouped>
<PRODUCT_TYPE_virtual>
    <reference name="product.description">
        <block type="catalog/product_view_type_virtual" name="product.info.virtual" as="product_type_data" template="catalog/product/view/type/default.phtml">
            <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.virtual.extra" as="product_type_data_extra" translate="label">
                <label>Product Extra Info</label>
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
</PRODUCT_TYPE_virtual>
```

Comment: Thanks @tim. I have added your code to the local.xml but without succes.

Comment: I'm awfully sorry. The correct name of reference block is `product.description`. I updated code in my answer. Please try it.