# Magento Override Model Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Backend_Media

Tags: magento, model, overriding

I use magento 1.7 and i try to override the model Model Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Backend_Media but this doesn't work.

My class :

```
class Mycompany_Mymodule_Model_Catalog_Product_Attribute_Backend_Media extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Backend_Media
```

My config :

```
... 
<model>
       <catalog>
            <rewrite>        <product_attribute_backend_media>Mycompany_Mymodule_Model_Catalog_Product_Attribute_Backend_Media</product_attribute_backend_media>
            </rewrite>
        </catalog>
    </model>
```

Can you help me ?

Thx

Comment: what are you trying to do? import images?

Comment: I just want to add few columns for each image.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to over write any core files at all.

What you need to do is create 1 new files:

```
  [Namespace]/[Module]/Block/[Adminhtml]/template/grid/renderer/Image.php
```

For the Image.php

```
      class [Namespace]_[Module]_Block_[Adminhtml]_Template_Grid_Renderer_Image extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Action {

  public function render(Varien_Object $row)
{
    return $this->_getValue($row);
}
public function _getValue(Varien_Object $row)
{
    if ($getter = $this->getColumn()->getGetter()) {
        $val = $row->$getter();
    }
    $val = $row->getData($this->getColumn()->getIndex());
    $val = str_replace("no_selection", "", $val);
    $url = Mage::getBaseUrl('media') . DS . $val;

    $out = $val. '<center><a href="'.$_url.'" target="_blank" id="imageurl">';
    $out .= "<img src=". $url ." width='60px' ";
    $out .=" />";
    $out .= '</a></center>';

    return $out;

}
  }
```

change code in the function as required to get to your folder, and error checking.

For the Grid.php add the following to one of your addColumns like below

```
        $this->addColumn('image1', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('attributeimages')->__('Image 1'),
        'align' => 'left',
        'index' => 'image1',
        'renderer' => '[module]/[adminhtml]_template_grid_renderer_image',));
```

Notice the ‘renderer’ option!

customize as you will

Comment: In fact, i want add some new text fields like "label" to add more informations to the image.

Comment: Columns i want to add are in Product edit, in image tab.
Any ideas ?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14184156/magento-add-product-info-to-more-info-tab that might help

Comment: I found a solution. I update attribute media_gallery to use my own backend_model which extend Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Backend_Media


Thx for your help.